# How to create typeclass with HList existential member

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, existential-type, hlist

I'm trying to create custom typeclass mimicking shapeless typeclasses. It looks like this:

```
  trait View[Record] {
    type Result <: HList
    def apply(r: Record): Result
  }

  object View extends LowPriorityLiftFunction1{
    type Aux[Record, L <: HList] = View[Record] {type Result = L}
    implicit def atView[Record: View] = at[Record](implicitly[View[Record]].apply)
  }
```

Suppose I'm providing it's functionality like this:

```
object toHView extends ->( (_:Int) + 1)

implicit def provideView[Record, L <: HList]
(implicit generic: Generic.Aux[Record, L],
 mapper: Mapper[toHView.type, L])
: View.Aux[Record, mapper.Out] =
  new View[Record] {
    type Result = mapper.Out

    def apply(r: Record) = mapper(generic.to(r))
  }
```

So if we define:

```
case class Viewable(x: Int, y: Int, z : Int)
case class NotViewable(x: Int, y: Long, z : Int)
```

then

```
val view = View(Viewable(1, 2, 3)) // is 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: HNil

val noView = View(NotViewable(1, 2, 3)) // is HNil
```

Trouble here if I try then to acquire

```
view.head
```

I'm having

> Error:could not find implicit value for parameter 
>   `c: IsHCons[View[Viewable]#Result]`

How could I define this typeclass to effectively use all it's type members later?

Of course i could get rid of type members:

```
trait View[Record, Result <: HList] {
  def apply(r: Record): Result
}

object View extends LowPriorityLiftFunction1{
  implicit def atView[Record, Result]
  (implicit view: View[Record, Result]) = at[Record](view.apply)
}

object toHView extends ->((_: Int) + 1)
implicit def provideView[Record, L <: HList]
(implicit generic: Generic.Aux[Record, L],
 mapper: Mapper[toHView.type, L])
: View[Record, mapper.Out] =
  new View[Record, mapper.Out] {
    type Result = mapper.Out  

    def apply(r: Record) = mapper(generic.to(r))
  }
```

but from this point at

```
val view = View(Viewable(1, 2, 3))
```

I'm getting an "*ambigous implicit values*" issue

Comment: off top of my head, you're not providing enough evidence that `Result` is not an empty `HList`, i.e. `HNil`.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella That's the point. AFAIK compiler should know `view` type **exactly**, so it should find corresponding `IsHCons` in `shapeless._`

Comment: All the compiler knows is that `Result` is an `HList`. I think the compiler is able to infer that it's not empty as some point of the computation, but the information is not preserved in the types, so when you try to access the head, it just falls back to the "Result in an HList" fact.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella So how compiler could know exact type for `shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper#Out` which is also just `type Out <: HList` at start, but could not find out my type that's just referencing it?

Comment: Do you have evidence the compiler knows the exact type of `Mapper#Out`? From what I see it simply knows it to be `<: HList`, which is good enough to assign it to `Result`.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella yes, compiler knows those type well, and i'm using It a lot. This is the point of the `shapeless` library. All those type members are derived, but those implementations are defined as recursive implicits or macro, so I'm trying to figure out why i cant refer to  another derived type without similar recursive implicit implementation

Comment: @GabrielePetronella [here the refined example for you](https://gist.github.com/Odomontois/167ba370177845960563). I'm getting rid of my typeclass and using pure shapeless instead. Compiler perfectly understands the types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here it is: change

```
implicit def atView[Record: View] = at[Record](implicitly[View[Record]].apply)
```

to

```
implicit def atView[Record](implicit v: View[Record]) = at[Record](v.apply(_))
```

The reason is that `implicitly` loses precision when dealing with refined type members, so instead of expected refined type of your `HList` (which in this case would be `Int :: Int :: Int :: HNil`), the compiler spits out a rather useless `View#Result`.

Using an implicit parameter instead of a context bound seems to preserve the refined type instead.

Also, shapeless' `the` is an alternative to `implicitly` which preserves type refinements, [although it doesn't seem to work in this case](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/439).

Here's an example of `implicitly` losing precision, taken from the [`the` implementation in shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/6fdc189b21ba2ea43a5c043044b86fedfb0e07b0/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeoperators.scala#L108):

```
scala> trait Foo { type T ; val t: T }
defined trait Foo

scala> implicit val intFoo: Foo { type T = Int } = new Foo { type T = Int ; val t = 23 }
intFoo: Foo{type T = Int} = \$anon\$1@6067b682

scala> implicitly[Foo].t  // implicitly loses precision
res0: Foo#T = 23

scala> implicitly[Foo].t+13
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Int(13)
  required: String
              implicitly[Foo].t+13
                                 ^

scala> the[Foo].t         // the retains it
res1: Int = 23

scala> the[Foo].t+13
res2: Int = 36
```

Comment: Using implicit instead of context bound worked magically, but  `the[View[Record]].apply(_)` unfortunately did not....

Comment: @Odomontois, I just realized the same and  updated the answer. I'm as clueless as you are.

Comment: This is another good argument for always providing type annotations on your `Case` instances.